# How do I replace imports when migrating from a Conan 1.x conanfile.txt to a Conan 2.0 conanfile.py?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, imgui, conan-2

I'm trying to get imgui working with OpenGL, using Conan to manage my dependencies. Imgui has backends which are used to hook into whatever rendering solution you're using.

The link below describes how to make those available to your project using Conan, by using the `[imports]` section of the conanfile.txt.

https://blog.conan.io/2019/06/26/An-introduction-to-the-Dear-ImGui-library.html

The `imports()` function has been removed from Conan 2.0, and I've seen some documentation saying you now need to use the `generate()` function in a conanfile.py to do the same thing. What I'd like to know is how to convert:

```
   [imports]
    ./misc/bindings, imgui_impl_glfw.cpp -> ../bindings
    ./misc/bindings, imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp -> ../bindings
    ./misc/bindings, imgui_impl_glfw.h -> ../bindings
    ./misc/bindings, imgui_impl_opengl3.h -> ../bindings
```

into what I need in the `generates()` function.

I haven't tried much yet, because I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The replacements of the legacy `[imports]` and `imports()` is an explicit `copy()` in the `generate()` method of the conanfile.py.

```
from conan.tools.files import copy

def generate(self):
    for dep in self.dependencies.values():
        copy(self, "*.dylib", dep.cpp_info.libdirs[0], self.build_folder)
        copy(self, "*.dll", dep.cpp_info.libdirs[0], self.build_folder)
```

More info in [the migration guide of the docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.59/migrating_to_2.0/recipes.html#removed-imports-method)